# R - Changing XTS Periodicity Subsetted By Variable

Tags: r, aggregate, subset, xts, quantmod

I currently have an xts with a character string column called "Symbol" and then several columns of numerical and character data. The data is mostly weekly and also at the end of the month. I would like to aggregate this data to a monthly periodicity for each of the "Symbols" present in the data, so in other words I want to get the monthly data for each symbol, not just for a random symbol which is chosen by quantmod. I tried using

```
to.period(df.xts, 'years', OHLC = FALSE)
```

from `quantmod` but ran into the problem that only one row was being chosen for each month.

Comment: Where is the test data? Post sample data..

Comment: Its just an xts that has a column with a string ticker/symbol like "AAPL" or "IBM" and then several other columns of data such as prices and other financial metrics.

Comment: You can't mix numeric and character data in the same xts object.  You should create a separate xts for each symbol

Comment: Okay. How would I do that? Or just assume that everything is character data. I can convert back to numeric later. I would prefer the second option if possible since I have around 300 tickers.